# FloatingActionButton placement

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I can't do the indent from the bottom. I have the indent in the design view window, but in a real device I haven't got the indent.

Design view window

[image]

A real device

[image]

Layout with FloatingActionButton:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/mainBackground">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/quantity_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/quantity_text_size"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/quantity_text"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/quantity_text"
    android:background="@drawable/quantity_style"
    android:id="@+id/quantity_field"
    android:hint="Количество"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/quantity_field_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/quantity_field_height"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black">
    <requestFocus/>
</EditText>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/save_floating_button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/floating_action_btn_margin"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:elevation="2dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/circleBackground"
    app:rippleColor="@color/changeFloatingButton"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="4dp"/>
```

Comment: Are you using `CoordinatorLayout` with FAB?

Comment: No, I am using RelativeLayout like the example above, nothing else

Comment: You should use coordinate layout with floating action buttons

Comment: But if a use CoordinatorLayout I need to change all Layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could use `android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"`

Edit:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@color/mainBackground" 
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">
```

Comment: I used it, but it didn't decide the  problem

Comment: Try this...

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/mainBackground"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

Comment: your welcome, I will edit the answer with the comment.. if anybody else needs.